# Get occurences of past 2 weeks on any given date

Tags: sql, presto

I have data like

```
id | date   |
-------------
 1 | 1.1.20 |
 3 | 4.1.20 |
 2 | 4.1.20 |
 1 | 5.1.20 |
 6 | 2.1.20 |
```

What I would like to get is to get the amount of occurrences an user with ID did in the past 2 weeks on any given date so basically "occurences between date - 14 days and date. I'm trying to categorize users by their amount of sessions past 2 weeks, and I'm following them by daily cohorts.

This query does not work since there can be days when the user does not log in aka does not have a row:

```
COUNT (distinct id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND  0 FOLLOWING)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Presto does not support `range()` window functions.  One method is a self-join/aggregation or correlated subquery:

```
select t.id, count(tprev.id)
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id and
        tprev.date > t.date - interval '13' day and
        tprev.date <= t.date
group by t.id;
```

This interprets your request as wanting 14 days of data, including the current day.

Another method that is much more verbose but might be faster is to use `lag()` . . . and `lag()` again:

```
select t.id,
       (1 +   -- current date
        (case when lag(date, 1) over (partition by id order by date) > date - interval '14' day then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when lag(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) > date - interval '14' day then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when lag(date, 13) over (partition by id order by date) > date - interval '14' day then 1 else 0 end) +
       ) as cnt_14
from t;
```